# Jerome’s translation of «κοινωνία» in the Vulgate of 1 Cor. 10:16

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians, latin-vulgate, latin

In the Vulgate of 1 Cor. 10:16, it is written,

> *calicem benedictionis cui benedicimus nonne communicatio sanguinis Christi est et panis quem frangimus nonne participatio corporis Domini est*

Why did Jerome translate the Greek word «κοινωνία» in 1 Cor. 10:16 into Latin once as *communicatio* and the other time as *participatio*?

Comment: Interesting! Did you notice that he also switched σώματος τοῦ Χριστοῦ --> corporis **Domini** (vs αἵματος τοῦ Χριστοῦ --> sanguinis **Christi**). Maybe he was working with a Greek text with the variant, but TR has both τοῦ Χριστοῦ.

Comment: A variant is more likely. It is the only place where Χριστοῦ is "translated" as *Domini*.  *Domini* is usually the translation of **κυρίου**. By the way, the Nova Vulgata has *communicatio sanguinis Christi* and *communicatio corporis Christi*, respectively.

Comment: @PaulVargas. It would be useful to know if this "variant" is recorded anywhere. The Nova Vulgata is of course a modern work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to believe that Jerome perceived any theological distinction between “communication” of Christ’s blood and “participation” of the Lord’s body. I can only suggest that he is using the rhetorical figure known as “interpretatio”, where a statement is repeated with substitution of one synonym by another, for the sake of stylistic variety.

There is some discussion here: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rzESGVfBEWIC&q=interpretatio#v=snippet&q=interpretatio&f=false

Esp. p. 335.

Comment: Wow, that is one insanely expensive tome. :)

Comment: Yes. It is no wonder that everything gets pirated on the internet.